# How to Align Floating Element to Centre of Container

Tags: html, css, grid, frontend

I am learning about frontend development.

I want to align the matrix and right-hand side column in the middle of the container. How can I go about doing this?

I created the following (it was made in react but this is the raw html):

[image]

I imagine there is a way to do this with HTML and CSS, but I am not sure how to go about it. I tried centering things but it does not seem to work.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto",
          "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans",
          "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      }

      code {
        font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
          monospace;
      }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
      .App {
        text-align: center;
        width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .matrix {
        float: left;
        display: grid;
        /* grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; */
        /* background-color: #2196f3; */
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .matrix-component {
        border-width: thin;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      }

      .rhs {
        display: grid;
        padding: 10px;
        /* float: right; */
      }

      .content {
        background: grey;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="App">
        <div class="content">
          <div>rows: <input />cols: <input /></div>
          <div class="matrix">
            <div>
              <input class="matrix-component" id="0" value="" /><input
                class="matrix-component"
                id="1"
                value=""
              /><input class="matrix-component" id="2" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input class="matrix-component" id="3" value="" /><input
                class="matrix-component"
                id="4"
                value=""
              /><input class="matrix-component" id="5" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input class="matrix-component" id="6" value="" /><input
                class="matrix-component"
                id="7"
                value=""
              /><input class="matrix-component" id="8" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="rhs">
            <input class="matrix-component" id="rhs0" value="" /><input
              class="matrix-component"
              id="rhs1"
              value=""
            /><input class="matrix-component" id="rhs2" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/main.65e0a7c3d67e68d31704.hot-update.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The best way (in my opnion) to implement such a thing this days is to use flex boxs. so to acomplish what you are looking for use a flex box. Here is an implementation of the css.

First lets group each column element together like this in you html.

```
<div class="new-div">
    <div>rows: <input />cols: <input /></div>
</div>
<div class="new-div2">
    <div class="matrix">
    <div>
        <input class="matrix-component" id="0" value="" /><input
        class="matrix-component"
        id="1"
        value=""
        /><input class="matrix-component" id="2" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="matrix-component" id="3" value="" /><input
        class="matrix-component"
        id="4"
        value=""
        /><input class="matrix-component" id="5" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="matrix-component" id="6" value="" /><input
        class="matrix-component"
        id="7"
        value=""
        /><input class="matrix-component" id="8" value="" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rhs">
    <input class="matrix-component" id="rhs0" value="" /><input
        class="matrix-component"
        id="rhs1"
        value=""
    /><input class="matrix-component" id="rhs2" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this css should do the trick.

```
   .content{
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        flex-direction:column;
    }
```

Tell me if this solves your problem. You can read more about flex-box's [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Here is a live demo of this solution https://codepen.io/hileamlak/pen/bGpqLgb

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it messes up my matrix inputs, and makes its structure irregular. Any way around this?

Comment: I noticed one more thing. That the div with the class name rhs isnt apearing along side matrix. I have a solution for that but it involves changing the html. is it ok if you alter your react.

Comment: why not do it simply with a grid? A grid without any float but specifying the exact locations

Comment: Would grid work if I am specifying the rows and columns programmatically for my matrix? I am not too familiar with it

Comment: of course, you set up a grid which is same a a table just that you position any item in every cell and even make it that it spans over multiple cells. all a question how how you position the items and how you define the grid rows and columns